# Eclipse PDT - Javascript Code Assist is not work?

Tags: php

I have try PDT 2.1.2 and 2.2 nighty build , both of them ,
javascript code assist is not work when editing php file. I  have check the JSDT,WTP Plugin is loaded and no error.
But when i open a *.js file, it works , is it any configuration i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Why would the **javascript** code assist help you when editing a **php** file? A javascript helper has no business in a PHP file.

Comment: <?php 
...
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
<style>...</style>
<body>
<?php
....
?>
</body>
<html>

html + php + css + javascript mixed, isn't common in nowadays?

Comment: It is, but I wouldn't expect a code-assist to account for that. And also, nowadays it would be better practice to put your javascript in an external file, and not inline in the page.

Comment: sure, load from extenal source is better.
But for a quick testing, learning etc.
Netbeans, Visual Studio, Zend Studio , Aptana Studio does html+css+js+php code assist in single php file , except PDT.
I believe it is a bug or i miss some config, PDT include WTP JSDT and default project property is referenced Javascript ECMA 3 library.